# Quartz.dll Error JobBuilder.cs file not found

Tags: c#, jenkins, quartz.net

Am using Quartz.Net to run a couple of scheduled jobs within a C# windows service hosted by Topshelf. I have started encountering a situation where the service does not run from source code and upon investigate I found the following error: 
The debugger could not locate the source file 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Quartz.NET\src\Quartz\JobBuilder.cs'.

Any body know how to sort this out.